# P-3 US visa application (artist visa) from outside of country of residence

Tags: visas, usa

We are a band of 6 touring Canada from 11 April until 21 April 2017. How can we apply for [P-3 US Visas](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/p-3-artist-or-entertainer-coming-be-part-culturally-unique-program) while on tour? We already have the required petition from our sponsor in Dallas, Texas.

Answer (score 2):

Have all your supporting documents ready together with the **approved** I-129 petition.

From the [State Department](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/nonimmigrants-present-visiting-canada-mexico.html) website:

> **How to Apply for a Visa at a U.S. Embassy or Consulate as a Third Country National in Canada or Mexico** Any third country national
>   (TCN)* present in the United States and visitors present in Canada or
>   Mexico who wish to apply for a nonimmigrant visa at the U.S. Embassy
>   or Consulates in Canada or Mexico, must make an appointment for an
>   interview. U.S.
>
> Applicants who wish to apply for their U.S. visa in Canada must visit
>   http://canada.usvisa-info.com/ to obtain information about how to
>   start their application for a U.S. visa at a consular section in
>   Canada. Applicants will be required to pay their visa application
>   processing fee prior to scheduling an appointment. Please see the
>   website for additional information.

Note that generally approval rates when approving in a third country are lower than when applying from home country.